# Is liquid silicone safe against a PCB in a mechanical keyboard?

Tags: pcb, short-circuit, corrosion

I just bought a mechanical keyboard and in the interest of keeping it quiet have found that some people recommend pouring liquid silicone into the keyboard case to form a silicone sound dampener that fits below the keyboard PCB.

I was wondering if silicone is a safe material to use next to/in contact with a PCB.  I'm wondering if it will short out the contacts on the board?  I'm also wondering if it will be corrosive?

Here's an example of someone making a silicone damper [How to Make a Silicone Mold](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEISslcF-Jk)

And the silicone used in the video: [Amazon: Miraclekoo Silicone Mold Making Kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07XHNDNJD)

Comment: Return the keyboard and buy a mechanical keyboard that uses mechanical keys of the volume vs tactile sensation that you want since that's why they make them a range of mechanical key switches. And have these people actually tried what they suggested? Because the sound from my mechanical keyboard comes from inside the switch, not from the key case bottoming out on the plastic below it; In fact, the key case does not bottom out at all. And silcones that are not neutral cure release acetic acid when curing.

Comment: Does the silicone have any data sheet or manual you can reference? If not, nobody can tell what's in it and whether it will short out or be corrosive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are hundreds of types of silicone, you need to read the application labels. Yes, there are many electronics safe silicone mixes, I used to use them on and near PCBs and components in the past. Also, make sure it is skin safe, since you will be handling the keyboard as well.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the PCBs of industrial products encapsulated with silicone to make them more robust. But, you must use the proper silicone.